# Is there a keyboard shortcut to close windows from the Windows 7 taskbar window selector?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

If, for example, Windows Explorer is in the first position of the taskbar and there are multiple explorer windows open, holding the Windows Key and pressing `1` will cycle through the available windows and display an `x` on the top-right of the selected item that can be clicked to close the window.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to close the selected window while still keeping the window list around (moving to the next item)?

[image: The Windows 7 Taskbar Windows Selector]

Comment: +1. Please post a screenshot anyway. I didn't know about this feature until I read the question.

Comment: @RandolphWest Done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As other have mentioned, there is no built-in keyboard shortcut. However, we can work some magic with [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com). I am going to use the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key to close the highlighted Taskbar window:

```
LastNumber := ""

~*1::LastNumber := "1"
~*2::LastNumber := "2"
~*3::LastNumber := "3"
~*4::LastNumber := "4"
~*5::LastNumber := "5"
~*6::LastNumber := "6"
~*7::LastNumber := "7"
~*8::LastNumber := "8"
~*9::LastNumber := "9"
~*0::LastNumber := "0"

*BackSpace::
    IfWinActive, ahk_class TaskListThumbnailWnd
    {
        WinKey := "LWin"
        if (GetKeyState("RWin"))
            WinKey := "RWin"
        
        SendInput, {Enter}
        WinClose, A
        
        SendInput, {%WinKey% Down}{%LastNumber% Down}{%LastNumber% Up}
    }
    else
        SendInput, {BackSpace}
    return
```

---

### Instructions:

1. **Press and hold** the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key down. *Do not release it until instructed!*
2. Press a number key until the target window is highlighted.
3. Press the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key. *The highlighted window will be closed! If the there is only one window left, then that window will be activated, otherwise the **window group** list will return.*
4. Repeat steps **2 to 3** to close more windows.
5. Finally, release the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key to be done.

This should work with **Taskbar thumbnails** enabled or disabled (as shown in the question).

Comment: +1 I like it. Thanks for this magic will test soon. :)

Answer (score 4):

looks like no - at least, without using an external program like AutoHotKey

List of shortcut keys from [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/keyboard-shortcuts)

Answer (score 3):

Steps:

1. WindowsKey+T
2. Left or Right key to get to the correct app
3. Up/down arrow to get to the correct app instance
4. Context menu key (right of spacebar)
5. C (for Close)

Comment: This closes the entire application, but I'm after a shortcut to close a speciifc window of the application.

Comment: I see. I'm not aware of a way to close a specific window.

Answer (score 0):

I found article, check this article .. maybe can help you

Here’s the full list of Windows 7 keyboard shortcuts or accelerator hotkeys available on the operating system level and also for several built-in application programs in Windows 7 ..
http://www.mydigitallife.info/windows-7-keyboard-shortcuts-accelerator-keys-or-hotkeys-full-listing/

For keyboard lover, Microsoft has added several keyboard shortcuts, hot keys or keyboard accelerators to make navigation and usage of Windows 7, especially the new Windows Aero snapping feature easier by using keyboard. 
http://www.mydigitallife.info/new-keyboard-shortcut-keys-hotkeys-in-windows-7/

Comment: This answer is too generic and doesn't answer the actual question

Answer (score 0):

There is not a keyboard shortcut to do exactly what you want.

You might be able to get close to what you want with a combination of Alt+Tab (holding alt, tapping tab) or with Aero enabled the same thing with Win+Tab. To close the active program use Alt+F4, to close just the active window of a program use Ctrl+F4.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is the keystroke to close a specific window of an application. Like if you have a lot of Explorer windows open and just want to close one. Or if you want to close one tab in your browser.

The list of Windows will remain visible as long as you hold the <kbd>Win</kbd> key. You could try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> while you hold the <kbd>Win</kbd> after using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to cycle to the window you want.

I can't test this since <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is mapped to *Settings* in Windows 8, but I did test it with another key combination, and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key combination still goes to the focused window while pressing the <kbd>Win</kbd> key. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is not a standard keyboard shortcut in Windows 7.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Alt+F4 which will close the current active window at that time

Comment: ALT-F4 doesn't work while cycling through taskbar windows without releasing windows key, which is against what I'm trying to do. Besides, ALT-F4 doesn't work for (for example) IE tabs, which appear in the window list in the taskbar.